# PHP - Creating a new object from an existing object without duplicating properties

Tags: php, clone

I'm using the **Symfony2 PHP framework** with **Doctrine ORM** and **mysql** for storing data.

My goal is to populate Doctrine entities(PHP objects) by loading the data from a legacy database system which returns the data in key:value pairs.

I have many `PHP objects('Company','Employee',etc.)` that extend the same `Abstract Class('AbstractDatabaseRecord').`

My `abstract class('AbstractDatabaseRecord')` has a property('`DatabaseTable`') which tells me which table to use when loading data for each object('Company','Employee',etc.).

My abstract class implements an `interface ('DatabaseLoadable')` which requires a method called `getColumns()` which should return an array of the columns that make up the objects properties. The interface also requires a method called `loadDatabaseData()` which should process the array returned from the legacy system, and run the appropriate setters to populate the PHP object.

I have a Symfony2 service(PHP class) called `LegacyDatabase` that has a couple methods called `findOne()` and `findAll().`

`findOne(AbstractDatabaseRecord $object, $id)` accepts an object, uses the DatabaseTable property to determine which table to query, and then queries that table using the id. It then populates the object using its `loadDatabaseData()` method and returns the object to me so that I can use it.

I think this one is structured OK, but I am not sure how to implement the `findAll()` function.

`findAll(AbstractDatabaseRecord)` accepts an object, uses the `DatabaseTable` property to determine which table to query, and then selects ALL records from that table. I then loop through the results and ideally will populate a new object for each record found, place the objects in an array, and return the array of newly created objects for me to use.

However in the function I only have the one instance of the object. What would be the best way to create additional instances given that I do now know the Concrete Parent class that is passed in?

From my research it seems like I want to clone the object to get a shallow copy, and then populate that new copy and add it to my array of objects. Is this the best approach?

Comment: At it's most simple: `$obj = new foo(); $class = get_class($obj); $otherobj = new $class;`. More eloborate can be done with `$reflection = new ReflectionObject($obj); $otherobj = $reflection->newInstance();` or other `->newInstance*` methods, for instance with arguments, or without calling the constructor.

Comment: thank you, I was not aware I could use new $class to create the object, that does simplify things

Comment: @Wrikken, that should be an answer.